# FirebaseRemoteConfigServerException when connect for remote config

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I have created a Firebase project and add `google-services.json` to app module.

I have setup Firebase remote config as follow :

```
private fun initFirebaseRemoteConfig() {
        val remoteConfig = Firebase.remoteConfig
        val configSettings = remoteConfigSettings {
            minimumFetchIntervalInSeconds = if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) 0 else 3600
        }
        //remoteConfig.setDefaultsAsync(R.xml.remote_config_defaults)
        remoteConfig.setConfigSettingsAsync(configSettings)
        remoteConfig.fetchAndActivate().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            val updated = task.result
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                Timber.d("Config params updated: $updated")
            } else {
                Timber.d("Unsuccessful")
            }
        }
    }
```

I receive following exception on this line `task.result` as follow :

```
com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException: com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.FirebaseRemoteConfigServerException: Fetch failed: The user is not authorized to access the project. Please make sure you are using the API key that corresponds to your Firebase project.
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu.getResult(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.0.2:15)
        at com.sample.android.tmdb.TmdbApp.initFirebaseRemoteConfig$lambda-0(TmdbApp.kt:34)
        at com.sample.android.tmdb.TmdbApp.lambda$P4-jkzwf9-IJZ17_EtnpghkBXis(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.sample.android.tmdb.-$$Lambda$TmdbApp$P4-jkzwf9-IJZ17_EtnpghkBXis.onComplete(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzi.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.0.2:4)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.tasks.zzb.dispatchMessage(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.0.2:6)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.FirebaseRemoteConfigServerException: Fetch failed: The user is not authorized to access the project. Please make sure you are using the API key that corresponds to your Firebase project.
        at com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.internal.ConfigFetchHandler.createExceptionWithGenericMessage(ConfigFetchHandler.java:380)
        at com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.internal.ConfigFetchHandler.fetchFromBackend(ConfigFetchHandler.java:333)
        at com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.internal.ConfigFetchHandler.fetchFromBackendAndCacheResponse(ConfigFetchHandler.java:278)
        at com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.internal.ConfigFetchHandler.lambda$fetchIfCacheExpiredAndNotThrottled$1$ConfigFetchHandler(ConfigFetchHandler.java:215)
        at com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.internal.-$$Lambda$ConfigFetchHandler$PAoFtfQiOtbXSTeK4H2aFJ-JNJI.then(Unknown Source:8)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzg.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.0.2:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
     Caused by: com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.FirebaseRemoteConfigServerException: Forbidden
        at com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.internal.ConfigFetchHttpClient.fetch(ConfigFetchHttpClient.java:195)
        at com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.internal.ConfigFetchHandler.fetchFromBackend(ConfigFetchHandler.java:307)
        at com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.internal.ConfigFetchHandler.fetchFromBackendAndCacheResponse(ConfigFetchHandler.java:278) 
        at com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.internal.ConfigFetchHandler.lambda$fetchIfCacheExpiredAndNotThrottled$1$ConfigFetchHandler(ConfigFetchHandler.java:215) 
        at com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.internal.-$$Lambda$ConfigFetchHandler$PAoFtfQiOtbXSTeK4H2aFJ-JNJI.then(Unknown Source:8) 
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzg.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.0.2:2) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

Comment: hi, were you able to solve the problem? i have the same issue but didn't find any helpful answer.(remote config api is enabled and there is no restriction on  any api)

Comment: In some countries firebase is not fully accessible due to sanctions such as Iran. Google recognizes from where you have connected even if you have VPN. @Mohammadcs